# Is there a best practice for accessible keyboard navigation through an undirected graph

Tags: html, navigation, keyboard, wai-aria, undirected-graph

TL;DR: Is there a recommended best practice to make keyboard navigation through an undirected graph accessible for visually impaired people?

I am currently working on an HTML based application that displays an undirected graph of buttons. Buttons are all contained in one `div` container. The paths that connect buttons visually are in a different container and are not relevant here, but the information that they transport about adjacency, of course. Each button can be used to trigger some action. I now wonder how I could make keyboard navigation accessible for visually impaired people.

Without any special treatment, a user would simply tab through all buttons. Information about adjacent buttons could, of course, be given via ARIA descriptions, but direct navigation to a specific neighboring button would not be possible. One would need to remember the label of the button and tab until it's found. That doesn't feel too user friendly.

I have browsed common [ARIA patterns](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/) and [ARIA roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles), but none does really seem to fit my purpose - I'd end up dynamically creating and restructuring treeviews or (tab)lists or worse with all kind of pitfalls probably.

Currently, my best idea is to simply use the `application` role for the buttons' `div` container with some custom keyboard commands to navigate. Navigation instructions would be announced via screen readers, of course. This could for instance mean: `tab` to enter/exit the application `div` and focus the entry button/previously selected button, `arrow` keys to cycle through the currently focused button's neighbors and the button itself announcing each label, and `space`/`enter` on the button would trigger the button's action and `space`/`enter` on a neighbor would make this the newly selected button.

That sounds feasible to me, but I wonder if there already is some best practice for this problem that I did not find myself.

Comment: I don’t believe I’ve seen any best practice for an _undirected_ graph. I’ve seen good examples of trees like organizational charts. Applying the _composite widget_ pattern with a single tab stop is a great idea. I believe to perceive a graph it’s most important to easily discover the edges? Is that what you’re referring to as neighbours, all nodes that are connected to the current button? I believe that it’s fine to use Space for selection, and Enter for actions.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your comment! I had never heard of the `composite` role before, but [MDN ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/composite_role) suggests it should not be used. The graph is like a map that the user can walk on from node to node (and neighbors are adjacent nodes to a node, yes). Think of it as the map of Super Mario World where users may need to clear a stage (node) to continue. That graph can have cycles, so a tree doesn't work. Having different actions for `Space` (e.g. move) and `Enter` (e.g. move and enter) might in fact work. Thanks again!

Comment: I’m not suggesting to actually assign the `composite` role, as it is an abstract role and *must not* be assigned. But it provides you with a name for what you are doing with focus management, which is a great idea. The [ARIA standard for `composite`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#composite) explains what it does: It indicates that the whole widget has a single tab stop and requires other means of navigation inside, for example arrow keys. Unfortunately no subclass role of `composite` applies to your case.

Comment: See also [APG’s Keyboard navigation inside components](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-6-keyboard-navigation-inside-components)

Comment: @Andy Thank you so much for your input! And yes, having a single tab stop and arrow keys for navigation would in fact be nice - and if there's some aria means to ensure that's clear, all the better, Thanks for that learning opportunity!